# Timestamp mismatch in Jenkins Maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins version of 2.289.3. And I am working on a Maven-TestNG Selenium project in it. I have added Build Timestamp plugin and setup it in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Build Timestamp with a pattern `yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss` of Asia/Calcutta. I am using Publish Html reports in Post Build action of that job's configuration. I have given path for HTML directory to archive is:

```
test-output\reports\report_${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
```

But when running this job, the time stamp is not matching for publishing html report. End-portion of my comsole output is given below:

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Aug 03, 2021 4:55:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 41.343 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

 Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

  [WARNING] Could not delete temp directory 
  C:\Users\CS1027C\.jenkins\workspace\SeleniumTestNG\target\surefire because Directory 
  C:\Users\CS1027C\.jenkins\workspace\SeleniumTestNG\target\surefire unable to be deleted.
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-03T16:56:22+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\CS1027C\.jenkins\workspace\SeleniumTestNG\pom.xml to 
MockTest/MockFrameTest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MockFrameTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
 [htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level 
 C:\Users\CS1027C\.jenkins\workspace\SeleniumTestNG\test- 
output\reports\report_2021.08.03.16.54.51 to 
C:\Users\CS1027C\.jenkins\jobs\SeleniumTestNG\htmlreports\HTML_20Reports
ERROR: Specified HTML directory 'C:\Users\CS1027C\.jenkins\workspace\SeleniumTestNG\test- 
output\reports\report_2021.08.03.16.54.51' does not exist.
Build step 'Publish HTML reports' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here the Chrome browser started at 4.55 but at post build action directory is created with timestamp containing 4.54. Why it is not taking the finishing time of the test? I can see a report folder generated at jenkins workspace is:

```
report_2021.08.03.16.55.36
```

Even I deleted the seconds from the time pattern, it is not matching with the generated report name. How can i fix this? Can anyone help me...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the most probable explanation is as follows:

[Build Timestamp plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timestamp/):

> Export build timestamps to build env variables.

This is similar to setting environment variables via build parameters and the inline help of ☑ *This project is parameterized* reads:

> Parameters allow you to prompt users for one or more inputs that will be passed into a build.

„*passed into a build*“ means that the environment variable is set before the first build step starts.

The output of a Freestyle test project with the following **Execute Windows batch command** build step confirms this (Timestamp plugin pattern is set to `HH:mm:ss,S`):

```cmd
@echo off
echo Build step begin: %time%
:: let 10 seconds pass 
ping -n 10 localhost > nul
echo Build step end: %time%
echo Build Timestamp: %BUILD_TIMESTAMP%
```

Console Output:

```
...
Build step begin: 21:19:33,88
Build step end: 21:19:42,90
Build Timestamp: 21:19:33,828
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..it works fine now. I have added ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP} in my build command and used its value in code.